# How to create a subversion repository

Tags: xcode, apache, macos

I have an apache server running and working with a username and password.  I want to create a subversion project - how do I connect to the apache server in Terminal (if I have to) and create the project structure etc before configuring in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to your server using SSH. The command would be:

```
$> ssh username@192.168.1.100
```

If your server has a non-standard SSH port of 22, then you'll need to add the port number:

```
$> ssh -p 1234 username@192.168.1.100
```

From the examples above, simply substitute 192.168.1.100 with your server's IP address. Substitute  "1234" with the SSH Port you're trying to connect to.

Finally, to create a new subversion repository, use the following:

```
$> sudo svnadmin create /my/svn_path/my_new_project
```

At this point, I would create the directory structure:

```
$> mkdir /my/project_path/
$> mkdir /my/project_path/trunk
$> mkdir /my/project_path/branches
$> mkdir /my/project_path/tags
$> mkdir /my/project_path/test
$> mkdir /my/porject_path/etc
```

Of'course, you don't have to follow the directory structure above.  It's just an example. But after you have your directory structure, you'll want to import it to the repository:

```
$> sudo svn import /my/project_path file:///my/svn_path/my_new_project -m "Initial Import of directory structure"
```

Once the directory structure has been imported, you should check out a copy of the repository to your local computer/desktop, and start coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
svnadmin create myproject
```

Will create you a repository

More complete information about creating repositories can be found here [Creating and Configuring Your Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.reposadmin.create.html)

Comment: don't I need to connect to the server first?  How do I do that